# Processing multiple different files into one output message

Tags: biztalk

I have five different excel files  (different structure and different data)
that will be processed into one output message (XML file).
Files arrive into different order , all files are required to create output xml file.

How can I do it in Biztalk ?

more specific questions:

1.Is that possible  to aggregate different type of messages in Biztalk and have message with multiple bodies ?

2.Can I aggregate 5 excel files into one message and then execute output pipeline to process all of them ?

Comment: That is a rather broad question. Look up the concepts of BizTalk convoy, correlation sets and multi-part maps.  You will also need to create or buy a pipeline component that can parse Excel files.   If you have specific problems that need solving, than update your question to address that.

Comment: 1) Yes, it is possible to aggregate different types of messages in BizTalk.  Usually this is achieved my mapping them all to a internal generic format and the use of multi-part maps to combine messages. 2) Again yes, it is possible to parse excel files (for example using the FarPoint Spread for BizTalk Server http://www.fpoint.com/biztalk/ ), and have them all output as a single message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would approach this problem as follows:

1. Create a new schema that represents the destination format, we will be mapping the incoming messages into this format.
2. Create schema's (probably Xml, not flat-file) that represent the incoming Excel spreadsheets. Disassemble the Excel files into their corresponding schema's either through a custom pipeline component (that isn't too difficult using the Excel SDK), or via a third-party tool (such as Farpoint Spread http://www.fpoint.com/biztalk/default.aspx), there is also an open-source component on codeplex at http://excel2007pipeline.codeplex.com/
3. Map the incoming xml message (disassembled Excel file) on a Receive Port into the destination format created in 1. Multiple Receive Locations can be used on a Receive Port, one for each incoming message format; likewise, multiple Maps can be specified on a Receive Port and the correct map will be selected automatically by BizTalk based on the incoming message type (schema namespace+root node name).

With regards to aggregating messages, take a look at parallel and sequential convoys; with regards to messages with multiple bodies, take a look at multi-part messages - both are out of the scope of this question unless you add further detail around what you are trying to achieve with these concepts.

Comment: If you want to add future proofing into the solution, rather than mapping directly to the destination format it is better to map to in internal generic format and map from that to your destination format.  This way if in the future this same data needs to go to another destination then you just need to create one new map, rather than 5.

Comment: I think that is what Nick means by *Create a new schema that represents the destination format*.

Answer (score 2):

Agree broadly with Nick's answer above, especially mapping messages in inbound pipelines.

However, I would not implement aggregation via sequential convoy pattern in BizTalk because doing so requires the use of singleton orchestrations, which are a BizTalk anti-pattern (and a support nightmare).

Basic parallel convoys can work because each "set" of 5 inputs will be routed to one instance of an orchestration which will terminate after finishing.

Comment: Yes, sequential convoys can lead to zombies!   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203853.aspx To be avoided.